# Do creatures with summoning sickness count as tapped?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

My friend played [Sheer Drop](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Sheer%20Drop) (Destroy target tapped creature) and targeted a creature of mine with summoning sickness. Is a creature with summoning sickness considered tapped?

Comment: That possible duplicate is the canonical question about summing sickness; it gives the meaning of summoning sickness and you can pretty clearly see it *doesn't* include tapping the creature.

Comment: I'm voting to leave this one open; I think it's alright to have a related question clarifying that Summoning Sickness *doesn't* do a particular thing.

Comment: @doppelgreener Fair enough, though the reason we ended up with that question is that people think summoning sickness does a million different things, and those questions were all getting answered with "no, it just does X, here's the rule, that's it, it doesn't do what you're talking about".

Comment: If it helps, I added a note on the duplicate's answer addressing this question.

Answer (score 2):

Saying a creature has "summoning sickness" just means that it hasn't been under its controllers control since the beginning of their turn and it doesn't have haste. Such a creature cannot attack and cannot cause itself to become tapped (i.e. you can't pay a Tap or Untap cost in an ability on that creature - it can still become tapped or untapped by other sources).

A "tapped creature" simply means a creature which has been turned sideways for one reason or another.

In other words, Sheer Drop only cares about whether or not the creature has been turned sideways, it doesn't care at all about when the creature entered the battlefield. If your creature is sick but hasn't been tapped, Sheer Drop can't target it.